# Laravel 4.2: Slow queries when using an external MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

When MySQL is on another server than the application the queries are very slow. It's not about the expected latency (network bottlenecks, etc); I never had this problem when I used Codeigniter. It doesn't look like a DNS issue either, and I experienced this problem on every vagrant machine and server I tested on.

Trying to figure out what is happening I wrote a simple test, running the same queries but using different approaches:

1. the PDO instance is created manually with DSN
2. the PDO instance is returned by `DB::getPdo()`
3. query builder

A screenshot with the test results: [image: here].

This is the code:

```
Route::get('/test', function(){


    $num_queries = 10;


    // manually creating a PDO instance with DSN
    Debugbar::measure('$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;port=$port;dbname=$db", $username, $password)', function() use ($num_queries){

        $hostname = Config::get('database.connections.mysql.host');
        $port = Config::get('database.connections.mysql.port');
        $db = Config::get('database.connections.mysql.database');
        $username = Config::get('database.connections.mysql.username');
        $password = Config::get('database.connections.mysql.password');

        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;port=$port;dbname=$db", $username, $password);

        for($i = 1; $i <= $num_queries; $i++)
        {
            $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?");
            $sth->execute(array($i));
            $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    });


    // using DB::getPdo()
    Debugbar::measure('$dbh = DB::getPdo();', function() use ($num_queries){

        $dbh = DB::getPdo();

        for($i = 1; $i <= $num_queries; $i++)
        {
            $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?");
            $sth->execute(array($i));
            $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    });


    // using the query builder
    Debugbar::measure('Query builder', function() use ($num_queries){

        for($i = 1; $i <= $num_queries; $i++)
        {
            DB::table('users')->where('id', $i)->get();
        }
    });

    return "<h1>$num_queries ".($num_queries == 1 ? 'query' : 'queries')."</h1>";
});
```

Note how bad the `DB::getPdo()` scales with multiple queries. Anyone else experienced this? What is happening here? I should point out that I don't have these problems when the MySQL database is on the same server as the application.

Answer (score 0):

The static call is using the same instance of PDO and therefore the same actual database connection behind the scenes every time.

The others create a new connection each time with the associated overheads involved.

Slow queries will be as a result of something else (perhaps indexes on production - debug the query using [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html)).

These debugging tests are leading you up the wrong path.